# How to Convert the table with column having two values(separate by , ) divide it into two values in two in pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

df.printSchema()

```
root
 |-- range: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- a: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- b: string (nullable = true)
```

df.show()

```
+------------+
|    range   |
+------------+
|[[3, Hello]]|
+------------+
```

My desired Output

```
+------------+
|  a  |  b   |
+------------+
|  3  | Hello|
+------------+
```

Convert the table with column having two values(separate by  , ) divide it into two values in two

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the pyspark version user deo's scala answer:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
j = '{"range":[{"a":3,"b":"Hello"}]}'
df = spark.read.json(sc.parallelize([j]))

#This convertes the array column to a struct column
df=df.withColumn('exploded', F.explode('range'))
#and the columns of a struct can easily by selected with * 
df.select('exploded.*').show()
```

You can also do this with a oneliner:

```
df.select(F.explode('range')).select('col.*').show()
```